# Spring Security Set Role On Registration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-security

I'm new to Spring security, so I've followed some tutorials but I'm having trouble understanding how the structure of roles really works under the hood. I have two tables, one for the User:

```
        @Entity
        @Table(name = "UserProfile", schema = "dbo", catalog = "DevTestTeam")
        public class UserProfileEntity implements UserDetails{

            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
            private long id;

            @Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
            private boolean enabled;

            @NotEmpty(message = "Enter a password.")
            @Size(min = 6, max = 15, message = "Password must be between 6 and 15 characters.")
            @Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 100)
            private String password;

            @NotEmpty(message = "Enter a username.")
            @Size(min = 6, max = 20, message = "Username must be between 6 and 20 characters.")
            @Column(name = "username", nullable = true, length = 20, unique = true)
            private String username;

            @OneToOne
            @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
            private RoleEntity role;

            public RoleEntity getRole() {
                return role;
            }

            public void setRole(RoleEntity role) {
                this.role = role;
            }

            @Override
            public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
                List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
                return authorities;
            }
```

and one for the role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Role", schema = "dbo", catalog = "DevTestTeam")
public class RoleEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
private long id;

@Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
private String name;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

My confusion comes when creating a new user. I have a registration form backed by a UserProfileEntity object, and that populates the username and password. Then obviously it's easy to setEnabled()=true (I left some of the getters/setters out of this code for clarity).

My question is how to set the role when instantiating a UserProfileEntity to be saved in the database. My role_id foreign key should just take an integer and return the role from the Role table, but I'm not sure how to express this when instantiating. I have a ROLE_USER in the roles table with an id of 1, and I feel like this is pretty simple to instantiate but I can't find the answer I'm looking for.

UserImpl:

```
@Service
public class UserProfileServiceImpl implements UserProfileService{
@Autowired
private UserProfileDao userDao;

@Override
public UserProfileEntity findByUser(String username) {
    return userDao.findByUsername(username);
}

@Override
public List<UserProfileEntity> findAll() {
    List<UserProfileEntity> list = userDao.findAll();
    return list;
}

@Override
public UserProfileEntity save(UserProfileEntity persisted) {
    userDao.save(persisted);
    return null;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    UserProfileEntity user = userDao.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found.");
    }

    return user;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need some repository method to obtain user role by name:

```
RoleEntity roleEntity = roleEntityRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER");
```

Then set that `RoleEntity` to `UserProfileEntity` before persisting it:

```
UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = new UserProfileEntity();
userProfileEntity.setRoleEntity(roleEntity);
userService.save(userProfileEntity);
```

What you also want is to leave your `UserProfileEntity` unextended. For Spring Security, you'll need `UserDetailsService` implementation:

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if (userProfileEntity == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Non existing user!");
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(userProfileEntity.getUsername(),
                userProfileEntity.getPassword(),
                Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userByUsername.getRoleEntity().getName())));
    }

}
```

However, I see that your requirements are quite simple - one role per user. Therefore, your `RoleEntity` could simply be an enum with predefined roles:

```
public enum RoleEntity {
    ROLE_USER
}
```

And in `UserProfileEntity` you'd use it like this:

```
public class UserProfileEntity {
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private RoleEntity roleEntity;
}
```

To persist user with role:

```
UserProfileEntity userProfileEntity = new UserProfileEntity();
userProfileEntity.setRoleEntity(RoleEntity.USER);
userService.save(userProfileEntity);
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the advice and different options. I will work with this this morning and see what I can come up with.

Comment: added my Impl class for reference, looks fairly similar to what you're suggesting.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I ended up using the first method you suggested and made a Dao for my RoleEntity. Also thank you for explaining your answer, this world of Spring security is pretty deep but I understand it a lot more now.